# GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount for google fit api ALWAYS prompt account selection

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-fit

I have an app which uses Google Fit. The integration code has been copied from google documentation:

```
if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
    GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this, // your activity
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                fitnessOptions);
} else {
        accessGoogleFit();
}
```

In the debug mode, everything works fine, but when my app downloaded from Google Play, it ALWAYS display a prompt for selecting the google account to use:

[image: prompt]

The problem appears only when app downloaded from google play. When app installed with adb, everything works fine.

It seems like, Google Play Services does not cache last selected account.

Please help me, where is the issue here?

Comment: I am designing n app too to access apple healthkit and google fit. I could do the apple part. But I am struggling with google fit. If you could share your repo it would be great mate.

Comment: How my repo can help to create a design? You shoul read Google Fit documentation first: [https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the production SHA1 certiciate. Google Play sign apk additionaly, so i have to use google play sha-1 from google play developer console for google api OAuth.